# Prevent to close a Backlog Item While sub tasks are opened on TFS Online

Tags: tfs, scrum, scrumboard

I need to have more control on backlog....
Years ago, we have created a project using a SCRUM Process... Not all developers pay attenction to use correctly TFS... There are many problems I'd like to solve step by step...

First one... I would like to prevent to close a PBI until subtasks opened exist. Can be possible? I have looked for on google... I have looked for settings everywhere on tfs but it seems it is not possible... I remember that on Jira could be possible... is it possible that Microsoft haven't implemented this option?

Do you have any idea to avoid that subtask remain opened when parents are closed?

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

There's no way to do that. The state of work items are totally independent of all other work items, including linked work items.

The best way to manage it at the moment that I've seen is to either:

1. Handle it via process: Be diligent about reviewing the sprint board and don't close user stories with open tasks
2. Write a work item query that shows you this information. Something like this will do the trick:
   [image]